# Insertion Sort with a helper method that returns an integer

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

I have a sort method intended to sort an array of doubles using insertion sort (method header shown below)

```
public static double[] sort(double[] array)
```

In this method I am expected to use a helper method that returns an integer (method header shown below)

```
private static int shift(double[] array, int index, double value)
```

Why would the helper method return an integer and not void if it is just shifting the elements in the array?

Comment: You should make some attempt to understand how an insertion sort is implemented and why you might use a `shift` operation.  What are the possible outcomes?

Comment: I understand how insertion sort is implemented, and I also know why having a shift operation is useful. But the way I see it, the shift method should be void since we are merely moving the elements in the array. What are we returning an integer for?

Comment: How do you know if it worked?

Comment: An array of random size is filled with random doubles from 0 to 1, exclusive of 1. It is then sorted and printed in increasing order.

Comment: I understand what your homework assignment is.  Since you have not provided any description of the `shift` function there's a number of different ways it could be implemented.  Almost all of them require some sort of indication of the result of the operation, if any.

Answer (score 0):

The shift method shifts all elements which are greater than the "value"(element being compared to the rest of the elements in the array) in the left part of the array by one position to the right and returns the correct position as an int.